# Update value in repeated node for YAML file (Ruby)?

Tags: ruby, yaml

Is there a built-in mechanism for updating a value for a given property in a YAML repeated node? I recognize that enumeration is a solution, but wondering if there is a better way.

Example:

```
require 'yaml'

yml = <<-eos
  common: &default_settings
    prop: 'xyz'

  something:
    <<: *default_settings
eos


config = YAML.load(yml)
config['common']['prop'] = "zzz"

p config
# I'm surprised the output is
# {"common"=>{"prop"=>"zzz"}, "something"=>{"prop"=>"xyz"}}
#
# I was expecting
# {"common"=>{"prop"=>"zzz"}, "something"=>{"prop"=>"zzz"}}
```

Comment: Why is this surprising? You are modifying the `Hash` after loading the `YAML`. This does not modify the `YAML` file at all. Once you `load` it is simply a `Hash` and will perform like a `Hash`

Comment: Ok. I understand @engineersmnky. I suppose my original question should be `is there a way to update a value for a given property in a YAML repeated node prior to loading the file`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check with the `object_id`, you can see `"common"` and `"something"` are having 2 completely different `Hash` objects. That's why changing one objects, *key's* value doesn't affect the other one.

```
require 'yaml'

yml = <<-eos
  common: &default_settings
    prop: 'xyz'

  something:
    <<: *default_settings
eos

config = YAML.load yml
config  # => {"common"=>{"prop"=>"xyz"}, "something"=>{"prop"=>"xyz"}}
config['common'].object_id # => 73499930
config['something'].object_id # => 73499700
```

And due to the above *fact*, when you did this `config['common']['prop'] = "zzz"`, it only modifies the hash `{"prop"=>"xyz"}` which is the value of `"prop"`, but not the `"something"`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my question:

```
require 'yaml'

yml = <<-eos
  common: &default_settings
    prop: 'xyz'

  something:
    <<: *default_settings
eos


parsed = YAML.parse(yml) # => #<Psych::Nodes::Document>

parsed.each do |n|
  if n.respond_to?('anchor') && n.anchor == "default_settings"
    n.children.each do |n|
      if n.style == 2
        n.value = 'zzz'
      end
    end if n.children
  end
end


p parsed.to_ruby
#{"common"=>{"prop"=>"zzz"}, "something"=>{"prop"=>"zzz"}}
```

Thanks again for the responses. Always happy to learn a better way if anyone has additional thoughts or ideas.